# Jenkins: Android Emulator wasn't created

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator

When creating an android emulator in jenkins I get the following in the console:

**Consola Jenkins Emulator Mobile**

````
$ C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe start-server
[android] Starting Android emulator
$ C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/emulator/emulator.exe -skin 480x800 -ports 5684,5685 -report-console tcp:5837,max=60 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_320_WVGA_android-29_x86 -wipe-data
PANIC: Broken AVD system path. Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT value [C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk]!
emulator: Android emulator version 30.4.5.0 (build_id 7140946) (CL:N/A)
[android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
[android] Stopping Android emulator
$ C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe kill-server
Finished: NOT_BUILT```
````

Comment: The path you've set appears to be non-sense: `C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk` (unless there would indeed be an SDK present at that location).

Comment: Locally I have ``C:\Android\sdk\.``, but jenkins automaticament generated the folder 'android-sdk' -> ``C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\android-sdk``

Comment: Log - emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5842